# JavaScript: Partial Function, why is necessary to do with Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, partial

I wanted to do a partial_left function that will be executed into an array, something liek that:

```
      array_1.map(partial_left1(equal));
      function equal(x){return x;}
```

, but I crushed when I pushed the variables of arguments into an other array(and not with the Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)). Because I wanna do other way, But I surprised when the result were differents:

```
      var array_1=[1,2,3];
```

with my method: th result is : [1,1,1]//doing reference only to the array[0]

with Array,prototype.slice.call: [1,2,3]//how I would want to be

this is my code, where I push the values of arguments in another array:

```
    function concat(arg1,arg2,n){
        for (var i = n; i < arg2.length; i++)
            arg1.push(arg2[i]);
        return arg1;
    }
    function partial_left1(f){
        var argum_apply=[];
        argum_apply=concat(argum_apply,arguments,1);
        return function(){
            argum_apply=concat(argum_apply,arguments,0);
            return f.apply(this,argum_apply);
        };
    }
```

And this is the code with Array.prototype.slice.call:

```
    function array(a, n) { return Array.prototype.slice.call(a, n || 0); }
    function partial_left2(f /*, ...*/) {
         var args = arguments;
         return function() { 
                var a = array(args, 1);
                a = a.concat(array(arguments));
                return f.apply(this, a); 
          };
    }
```

A simple definition of equal with partial:

```
    var equal_left1=partial_left1(equal);
    var equal_left2=partial_left2(equal);
```

Here are the results, and I don't know why they are differents?

```
    var array_1=[1,2,3];
    alert(array_1.map(equal_left1));//1,1,1
    alert(array_1.map(equal_left2));//1,2,3
```

Someones who knows please explain me what are the differences between "Concat" and use "Array.prototype.slice.call"?

Answer (score 0):

One of the bad design decisions: `arguments` is not an array.  It is `array-like`, in the sense it has a `length` property.

You can't call the `concat` method of `arguments` because it doesn't exist.

`Array.prototype.slice.call` uses the `slice` method from the arrays and invokes it -- it is a quick and easy way to turn something `array-like` to a proper array.

You can do the same thing with a loop, if you want:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arguments[i];
}
```